# Why is "import std;" giving a "could not find module file for module std" error?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I have just started learning C++, so I am probably overlooking something, but I cannot figure out how to get the import keyword working for my first hello world program. I have made sure I am using C++20, and when I use `#include <iostream>;` instead of `import std;` the program works fine.

This is the entirety of my code, copied from *A Tour of C++ Third Edition*:

```
import std;

int main() {
    std::cout << "helloworld";
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2022, and the editor shows two errors:

- 'could not find module file for module std' under `std`
- 'namespace "std" has no member "cout"' under `cout`

Comment: It works for me if I add `int` as the return type for `main`. Did you install module support in the installer and select Yes in your project under C/C++/Language/Enable Experimental C++ Standard Library Modules? There's also an option in the same tab for Build ISO C++23 Standard Library Modules that I have set to Yes although I do not remember ever changing it.

Comment: @Retired Ninja   I Forgot to add int, I'll change it in the question. I found a module called "C++ Modules for v143 build tools (x64/x86 - experimental)" under individual components in the installer, if that's what you were referring to. After installation, nothing changed. I have both of those options set to yes as well.

Comment: You do need to set the C++ version to latest, not 20, in order for it to work.

Comment: This syntax is very new, introduced in C++23 which hasn't even been published yet. Don't expect it to work without issues on compilers yet. And generally tooling for modules isn't good yet. I would not recommend modules (`import`/`export`/`module` keywords) to be used when first learning the language.

Comment: This is a C++23 feature rather than C++20.

Answer (score 3):

It is no longer be necessary to use "Enable Experimental C++ Standard Library Modules". That refers to an older implementation of the C++ Modules TS.

This article, from June 8, 2023, tells how to enable support for `import std;` and `import std.compat;` from the command line: [Tutorial: Import the C++ standard library using modules from the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-import-stl-named-module?view=msvc-170).

It links to this note on how to enable support within the IDE: [Build ISO C++23 Standard Library Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/c-cpp-prop-page?view=msvc-170#build-iso-c23-standard-library-modules).

The following is my summary of the IDE method. I tested with this short program that executed successfully.

```cpp
// main.cpp
import std;
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Starting in Visual Studio version 17.6, you can enable support for `import std;` and `import std.compat;` in the IDE    by setting two project properties.

In project properties, under "C/C++", go to the page labeled "Language". On this page set the two properties given below:

###### C++ Language Standard

> Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft (/std:c++latest)

###### Build ISO C++23 Standard Library Modules

> Yes

That's it. BTW, the second was already set to "Yes" on my installation. It probably is on your version, as well.

Comment: `the second was already set to "Yes" on my installation` Yeah, exactly. And I still get the error with latest and Build ISO C++ 23.

Comment: `import std` does not mix well with programs that import individual header files, e.g., `import <iostream>`. With a few isolated exceptions, it also does not work with files that include standard headers, such as `#include <iostream>`. So, test in a new project. Set the properties. Add a `.cpp` file named `main.cpp`. Paste in the program above. If that won't compile, then I don't know what to suggest, beyond the usual "update to the latest version of Visual Studio," etc.

Comment: Also, check the [answer by @Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77438831/22193627). He had to add `std.ixx` to his project "Resource Files."

Answer (score 1):

As I struggled a while with the same issue, and VS 2022 did not find the Standard Library modules automatically (as said by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/c-cpp-prop-page?view=msvc-170#build-iso-c23-standard-library-modules), here is what I did:

I checked if I was able to build the modules on the command line, as described in [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-import-stl-named-module?view=msvc-170](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-import-stl-named-module?view=msvc-170), mentioned by @tbxfreeware.

That worked fine. I checked the content of %VCToolsInstallDir%\modules (%VCToolsInstallDir% mappes to :\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\modules on my machine), where modules,json, std.compat.ixx, and std.ixx were present.

As the modules still were not found, I added just std.ixx to the existing resources (Resource Files) of my project, with /std:c++latest compiler option set.

Now the "Hello World" code compiled and ran.

Think it is worth to mention that including std.compat.ixx automatically includes std.ixx too. When both std.compat.ixx and std.ixx are added to the Resource Files of the projects, on first build / rebuild I always received an error telling the compiler was not able to open output file '\x64\Debug\std.ixx.ifc'. Building the project then again worked well. The error makes sense to me, as std.ixx is built twice in this scenario, so the compiler "sits" on the output file already.

So, its either adding std.ixx or std.compat.ixx to the Resource Files of the project, not both. More details on when to use std.compat can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/tutorial-import-stl-named-module?view=msvc-170#import-the-standard-library-and-global-c-functions-with-stdcompat.